# Jenkins automate build based on email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new user to Jenkins and planning to automate the build process. How to trigger a build in Jenkins by receiving an email and using email content during the build process?

Can anyone please suggests what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plugin does what you want:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin

It checks an imap mailbox for incoming email and injects information into the build process.

Documentation:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin